# How to create a view for a item in a table from a web api in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a table in Angular, the table is populated by data from a web api. What I want to know is, the first column is a request number from the api, this needs to be a link and then when the user clicks on it they can view details of that request. My table code is:

```
    <tr class="" *ngFor="let incident of data">
                  <td><a href="">{{incident.number}}</a></td>
                  <td style="text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{incident.severity}}</td>
                  <td>{{incident.number}}</td>
                  <td>{{incident.urgency}}</td>
                  <td style="text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{incident.sub}} 
    </td>
    </tr>
```

This is more of a how to question?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Answer (score 0):

use router link `<a [routerLink]="routerLinkVariable"></a>` In Single Page Application (SPA), routerLink  will load the component into router-outlet without reloading/refreshing the page. On the other hand, clicking on a **href** link will refresh/reload the whole application or reset the application back to the start (state will get reset).